# How should nested JSON objects be passed to Lambda Functions from CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3, aws-ssm

From an Automation SSM Document, which has been deployed via CloudFormation Stack, I trigger Lambda functions CopyToMultipleAccountsLambdaFunction and CopyToMultipleRegionsLambdaFunction. These receive a malformed payload which makes the lambda functions fail.

The exact error is as follows:

```
Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character ('9' (code 57)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries at [Source: (byte[])"{"MetadataJSON":["{"MyAccountNo":"eu-central-1,eu-west-1,eu-west-2"}"],"AmiIDParamName":"/GoldenAMI/OperatingSystemName-OperatingSystemVersion/ProductName-ProductVersion/1", "MetadataParamName":"/GoldenAMI/OperatingSystemName-OperatingSystemVersion/ProductName-ProductVersion/1/temp"}"; line: 1, column: 22] (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestContentException
```

The only difference from all other payloads passed to lambda functions in the pipeline I have deployed is that the parameter MetadataJSON is missing. This parameter has a value which is a kind-of-JSON object. (I say kind of as the “key”: “value” seems weird…)

Based on the [AWS Golden Image Pipeline Guide](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-golden-ami-pipeline-sample/blob/V-1.0/Golden-AMI-Pipeline-Guide%20V1.0.pdf) the value that I pass (purely for testing purposes) is as follows

```
"MetadataJSON":{
  "Type":"String",
  "Default":"{\"MyAccountNumber\":\"eu-central-1,eu-west-1,eu-west-2\"}",
  "Description": "Metadata of accounts and regions for distributing the golden AMI."
},
```

You can find the code for the two lambda functions [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-golden-ami-pipeline-sample/blob/V-1.0/Gold-AMi-Stack-CFT-CI.json#L1778) and [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-golden-ami-pipeline-sample/blob/V-1.0/Gold-AMi-Stack-CFT-CI.json#L1921)

The trigger for these two lambda functions is given by the Automation SSM Document CopyAndShare, which you can find [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-golden-ami-pipeline-sample/blob/V-1.0/Gold-AMi-Stack-CFT-CI.json#L1995)

I read online one potential resolution is to encapsulate the object in a [ ] construct. I tried it, but it doesn’t work, and the error Lambda raises is Unknown.